# Openin MSN Messenger windows through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how to create a launch script to open Windows Live Messenger window.
I tried several and also using LaunchIMUI (for windows messenger) but with no luck. I have used some to open Skype for example, but couldnt find one for messenger.

Does anybody know somehow to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an odd question.

Javascript runs inside your browser and is sanboxed inside your browser. If javascript is able to execute program on the machine outside the browser, this would be a huge security issue.

Please share with me how you opened Skype from javascript...

Comment: But is there a way by PHP to open this MSN MEssenger or neither?

Thanks!

Comment: With php you could open it on the server!! Not on the client. However, you can relay it from client to server if needed